# Responsive Form without await

Tags: c#, winforms

Suppose you are doing a lot of stuff inside a form.

```
while(true)
{
    DoStuff();
}
```

This results in problems: while the loop is executing the form stops redrawing and locks up.

The goto solution is to use async/await.

```
while(true)
{
    await Task.Run(DoStuff);
}
```

...or some variation on that.

However if the cycle period is small this will result in new task objects popping up and GC struggling to  disintegrate them. Though a modern machine can handle this without a problem, I think it is still desirable to avoid that.

I have found that you can solve the redraw problem with `Control.Invalidate()`. It will redraw the form, as long as it stays in focus.

```
while(true)
{
    DoStuff();
    MyControl.Invalidate();
    //or
    MyForm.Refresh();
}
```

However I have no idea how to avoid the locking.

As far as I know forms run on one thread, so while my code is executing the form is unable to process windows messages. In a cpp program you would just go through the message buffer every cycle yourself. But what can you do here?

Comment: You should follow the async/await path.

Comment: Can't you put the while loop inside the `Task` ?

Comment: @Cid you can only modify the form from the main thread.

Comment: In WPF one can dispatch some task to the main-thread from any other thread, is this also possible in winforms?

Comment: Yes, in winforms it is `Control.Invoke()`.

Comment: _"In a cpp program you would just go through the message buffer every cycle yourself. But what can you do here?"_ well what do you do in `DoStuff()`? I think you approch is generelly illsuited for the winforms framework.

Comment: @Ackdari Yes, but if you use async/await wise enough that will all be done behind the scenes

Comment: @SirRufo doesn't this depends on whether `DoStuff()` can be made _truely_ async, I mean if is does CPU heavy stuff then is needs to be performed on another thread and then I would suggest to use `Control.Invoke()` to dispatch any UI related task back to the UI-Thread.

Comment: @Ackdari You can use Task.Run for cpu-bound code to run in background without blocking and await that task. Read https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html

Comment: An alternative to `async/await` would be to use the `BackgroundWorker` which can be nice for instances where you want it to be running all the time and still get UI updates.

Comment: @WSC Yes, thank you. It works just as I need, as far as I can tell. There was an answer that recommended this option, but it was deleted for some reason.

Comment: Read [Stephen Cleary: Task.Run vs. BackgroundWorker](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/09/taskrun-vs-backgroundworker-round-5.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I wanted is:

```cs
while(true)
{
    DoStuff();
    MyForm.Invalidate();
    Application.DoEvents();
}
```

Though arguably a better solution would be not to use C# for my problem...

Answer (score 1):

> However if the cycle period is small this will result in new task objects popping up and GC struggling to disintegrate them. Though a modern machine can handle this without a problem, I think it is still desirable to avoid that.

Allow me to quote Donald Knuth:

> Programmers waste enormous amounts of time thinking about, or worrying about, the speed of noncritical parts of their programs, and these attempts at efficiency actually have a strong negative impact when debugging and maintenance are considered. We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil.

In other words, use `await Task.Run`. ***If and only if*** performance analysis indicates that there are performance problems, then explore alternative solutions. And if performance analysis does indicate a problem, the first alternative solution I would suggest is increasing the amount of code within the `Task.Run`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go old school and use manual threading, your code would look similar to your original idea.  I've placed some comments in key areas to bring your attention to caveats.  The BackgroundWorker control takes care of this type of stuff for you:

```
private System.Threading.Thread T;

private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    T = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(backgroundThread));
    T.IsBackground = true; // optional: allows program to close even when T is running
    T.Start();
}

private void backgroundThread()
{
    while (true)
    {
        DoStuff();

        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate() {
            // It's safe to update the UI from within this block
            //
            // This should be done sparingly or it negates the
            // whole process of using a separate thread!
        });

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100); // slight CPU break
    }
}

private void DoStuff()
{
    // foo();
    // bar();
    // stuff();
}
```